# SQL Server 2005 backup restore failing (with folder permissions)

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7, permissions

I am trying to restore a database (from file `thedb.bak`). I am using [SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) edition 2005 on a Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit machine.

When I try to restore I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\Thedb.MDF'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

My username (antoniocs) is an Administrator. I have edited the permissions in the folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\`) so that the user AntonioCS has full control.

I really need to restore this backup. What am I missing?

Note: I am using the Windows authentication to login. Should I try another user (the one I use is an administrator in the machine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account running the SQL Server service requires permissions on that folder.

You may be connected to SQL Server, but actions are done in the service account context: not you.

Run services.msc from command line, see what account is used, permission this folder accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! This really was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database that uses `Thedb.MDF`? I ran into this error when I tried to restore a database over a file that SQL Server used. From the restore window, choose Options and change the path or the filename from the "Restore the database files as".